# React , Express, "TypeError is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, typeerror

```
var express = require('express')

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;     

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started'))
```

Is there any error here ?

VS code says

> TypeError: app.listen is not a function

Comment: Please share all the relevant code.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

now working just reinstalled express
npm install express